# How can i add reference dll for an asp .net application in IBM blue mix?

Tags: mongodb, cloud, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud

How can i add reference dll for an asp .net application in IBM blue mix ?
 Am creating an asp.net application using IBM blue mix. I want to connect with Mongodb  from my application. How can i add dll for Mongodb c# drivers from IBM blue mix ? Am using IBM git editor to edit my code. I don't see any reference folder in git editor. So where can i add this dll for Mongodb  ?

I can see a project json file,

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web-kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel"
    }
}
```

but not sure about this file. Do i need to configure here ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of worrying about including the dll I'd suggest looking into the [MongoDB.Driver Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/). Then you only need to add the dependency to your project.json to be able to use it in your application. It will be downloaded the first time the application stages.

Comment: How can i add the dependency ? below is my current dependency file,    {
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web-kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel"
    }
} i need to change this file only correct? Can u give some example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You just add "MongoDB.Driver": "2.0.1" after your other dependencies in the section labeled "dependencies". Visual Studio provides intellisense autocomplete to assist in finding packages but this is simply a json text file.  You list your dependencies and they are resolved at build time.